# Checking independence in non-stationary timeseries

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, independence, stationarity, change-point

I am wanting to apply a changepoint detection method to a timeseries but an assumption is that the data points are independent from each other.

I was wondering if there is a way to check this when the data might be non-stationary? The reason I ask is that when I have done correlation plots or the Ljung-Box test on synthetic non-stationary timeseries, they show up sometimes as showing correlation even thought the samples are independent from each other.

Comment: This may depend on the type of nonstationarity. Is it a unit root? Nonconstant variance? Something else?

Comment: @RichardHardy Nonconstant variance and potentially nonconstant mean

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question.  You cannot check this assumption before analysis because the changepoints make the data non-stationary and so standard stationary methods for assessing independence/correlation are no longer valid.

The best way is to perform a changepoint analysis and then look at the residuals (remove the time varying mean/variance) to see if they are independent/correlated.

You can find an example of how to checking the assumptions of a changepoint analysis [here](https://github.com/rkillick/intro-changepoint-course/blob/master/IntroCptWorkshop.pdf), pg 44 onwards.  The example given there is a change in mean but the approach generalizes to other changepoint models.

Comment: Thank you. So suppose we have a changing variance and mean, would I centre the data and then normalise by the standard deviation?

Comment: Yes, you subtract the fitted mean for each segment and then divide by the segment standard deviation. This should then be the error distribution of the original model, often Normal(0,1).